# Facebook login how to proceed

Tags: facebook, authentication

I am new to facebook-login system. I want to ask that after getting the permission, how to use the code that is passed as a get parameter to retrieve the token for the user in PHP SDK...

Comment: Please explain your question better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you didn't even read the Facebook documentation

You can start reading this

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/

And here you can learn how to retrieve a token with the php SDK
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/